# DataTemplateSelector is not executed when items are cleared and added to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

in my .Net Maui App I want to display Data stored in an `ObservableCollection` using a `DataTemplateSelector`. Therefore I created an example using Microsoft's documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/datatemplate?view=net-maui-7.0

I have an `ObservableCollection<DataBaseItem> DataBaseItemsFiltered;` in a ViewModel. In the View I got a CollectionView to display the Data using a `DataTemplateSelector`.

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding DataBaseItemsFiltered}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DBISelector}">
```

Everything works as expected until I update the `ObservableCollection`. This is what it looks like after starting the app. Every item owned by "BestCompany" is highlighted (as expected).

[image: Expected result]

But if I update/filter the 'ObservableCollection' (For testing purpose just clearing and adding the originial items)

```
[RelayCommand]
void Filter()
{
    ...
    DataBaseItemsFiltered.Clear();
    foreach (DataBaseItem item in dataBaseItems)
    {
        DataBaseItemsFiltered.Add(item);
    }                
}
```

This happens.

[image]

This behaviour alternates every time I am calling the `Filter()` function.
I found out that only on start up the custom DataTemplateSelector is called for each Item in the collection. Then it is never called again.
However if I change the `Filter()` function to instantiate a `new ObservableCollection`

```
DataBaseItemsFiltered = new(dataBaseItems);
```

It works and while debugging I can see that everytime the DataTemplateSelector is called (as expected) when I call the filter function.

My question: Does anybody how to fix this? Am I using the `ObservableCollection` in a way that it is not intended for? Is there a workaround to tell the view that the DataTemplateSelector has to be called for each item in the collection view?

If you need more code just tell me. And thank you in advance.

---

Edit 19.12.2022
Answering ToolMakerSteve's questions.

1. Yes DataBaseItemsFiltered is a public property (generated by MVVMToolkit)

```
[ObservableProperty]
ObservableCollection<DataBaseItem> dataBaseItemsFiltered;
```

2. Yes. Just tested
3. The Filter Function is bound to a SearchBar's SearchCommand

```
                <SearchBar Grid.Column="1" 
                           SearchCommand="{Binding FilterCommand}" 
                           Text="{Binding CompanyFilterText}"/>
```

---

Edit 2 19.12.2022
Answering Liqun Shen-MSFT's questions.

Apparently the `ObservableCollection` (OC) behaves like this:

1. If items are added and the count is bigger than it was since instanciation of the OC. The DataTemplateSelector will be triggered.

Example: Deleting 1 item from then adding 2 times to the OC will assign the template of the deleted item to the first item being added (not triggering the DataTemplateSelector). For the second item the DataTemplateSelector is triggered (Correct template is being assigend)

2. Deleting n items and adding n items will assign the templates LIFO like.

Example:
Deleting one item with DataTemplate1.
Deleting another item with DataTemplate2.
Adding a new item => DataTemplate2 is being assigned (no matter what).
Adding a new item => DataTemplate1 is being assigned (no matter what).

Comment: **1)** Add to question the declaration of `DataBaseItemsFiltered`. Is it a public **property**? That is, it has a `get`. **2)** As a test, if you add `bool good = MainThread.IsMainThread;` as first line in `Filter`, then set a breakpoint on next line, is `good` `true`? **3)** Where is `Filter` called from? Is it a button press? If "yes" and "yes and "yes"", then this might be a Maui bug.

Comment: Did the  CollectionView work well when simply remove or add  a new item in the ObservableCollection?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT  this is a bug.  merely removing and adding a new item with a different DataTemplate that was previously set, does not fix the issue.  Clearing the collection doesnt fix the issue. Only making sure the item is wrapped in a layout fixes the issue.

Comment: Was this ever reported as a bug? Now that i ran into yet another issue (https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9567) that demands i wrap CollectionView Items in Borders again rather than Layouts i cant make any condition satisfied...

Comment: I cannot remember reporting this because I found a similiar bug report. I think I  read that you shouldn't use Frame but border. But no guarantee this statement is true, since I didn't dig deeper and it is too long ago.

Comment: finally reported this. https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/21252 . ironically AFTER finding an elegant workaround

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to somehow get rid of the problem.
As a side note: This problem does not occur on android. Cannot check for iOS and MAC.

So the issue seems to be the `DataTemplate` (or more precisely its child) used in the `DataTemplateSelector`.

---

**Working version**

If the child inherits from `Layout` (`Grid`, `VerticalStackLayout` etc.), everything will work as expected. No matter what, the `DataTemplateSelector` is triggered when an item is added to the ObservableCollection.

Example: (Using `Grid` as ChildElement of the `DataTemplate`)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateDefault_Good">
    <Grid>
        <Frame>
            <HorizontalStackLayout x:DataType="local:SomeItem"
                                    Spacing="30">
                <Label Text="{Binding Id}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

**Version not working**

Otherwise (child of `DataTemplate` inherits from `View` or `ContentView`) will show the behaviour I described in my question. DataTemplateSelector only triggers, when an items is added to the ObservableCollection and the size of the ObservableCollection is bigger than it ever was since instantiation.

Example: (Using `Frame` as ChildElement of the `DataTemplate`)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateDefault_Bad">
    <Frame>
        <HorizontalStackLayout x:DataType="local:SomeItem"
                                Spacing="30">
            <Label Text="{Binding Id}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Frame>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

I'd appreciate any further explanation to this behaviour. Might this be a bug and shall be reported?

Comment: Yes its obviously a bug that should be reported. Yes I too want a better explanation, 
ive now wasted so much time with the issue. glad to come across the answer

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer to this.

The `DataTemplateSelector` will be forced to be reread if the `ItemTemplate` property of the `CollectionView` is nullified and then re set (Using the same `DataTemplateSelector` instance works fine)

The `ObservableCollection` assigned to the `ItemsSource` property of the `CollectionView` will have a `CollectionChanged` `event`. Subscribe to it check if the `NotifyCollectionChangedAction = Reset` (as is issued upon calling `ObservableCollection` `Clear` method) Then in the `event` handler you can null and set the `DataTemplate` again as described above like so:

```
myObservableCollection.CollectionChanged += (sender, notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) =>
{
    if (notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
    {
        ItemTemplate = null;
        ItemTemplate = dataTemplate;
    }
};
```

Now when the list is repopulated, the items get a new `DataTemplate` just like it did the first time.

Best of all, this is an elegant solution to something that is surely a bug.

Credit [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597683/how-to-force-re-selection-of-datatemplateselector) giving me the idea

Don't forget to like and subscribe!