# Change listview selecteditem datatemplate UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to change the datatemplate of a selected item in a listview, everything I have found is overly complicated or obsolete.
I've tried using behaviours but it still doesn't work. this is what I am after

```
<UserControl.Rescources>

  <DataTemplate x:DataType="dt" x:Key="notselected">
      <Grid>
       <Textblock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="White"/>
       <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/myimage.png"/>
     </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate x:DataType="dt" x:Key="selected">
      <Grid>
       <Textblock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="Black"/>
       <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/myselectedimage.png"/>
     </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>

</UserControl.Rescources>


 <ListView x:Name="listview" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TMP1}">
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
       <StaticResource ResourceKey="ListViewItemStyle1"/>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

and just to have it switch to TMP2 while selected
is this possible?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP: DataTemplateSelector and SelectedItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249232/uwp-datatemplateselector-and-selecteditem)

Comment: ive been playing about with that solution for the last hour and I cant get it to work

Answer (score 0):

In your `ListView` you need to set `ItemTemplateSelector` to your implementation of `DataTemplateSelector`. In the code above, you have set `ItemTemplate`

Assuming `TMP1` refers to your `DataTemplateSelctor` it would look like `<ListView x:Name="listview" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TMP1}"`...